# Multiple recursions in SQL tree

Tags: sql-server-2008, tree, common-table-expression

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a  table which details useraccess to groups with two  columns - `userid int` and `groupid int` (let's call it `tbl_access`). Each user can have access to multiple groups at any level in the tree.

There is a second table of groups defining a tree structure with three columns - `groupid int`, `groupfather int`, groupname nvarchar(32) (top level groups have a value of -1 for `groupfather`) - let's call it `tbl_groups`.

I am trying to write a function where given a `userid`, the function will look up all the groups the user can access in `tbl_access`, and for each group it will then find all of child nodes, and return a combined distinct list of all the groups the user has access to).

I have tried using CTE but that only got me so far as getting all the child nodes of one group, not all the child nodes of all groups.

What i have for now is :

```
CREATEFUNCTION [DBO].[FUNC_ALL_CHILDGROUPS] (@GROUPID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    WITH ALLGROUPS (GROUPID, GROUPFATHER) AS 
    (
        SELECT GROUPID, GROUPFATHER 
        FROM 
            TBL_GROUPS 
        WHERE GROUPID = @GROUPID 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT TBL_GROUPS.GROUPID, TBL_GROUPS.GROUPFATHER 
        FROM 
            TBL_GROUPS 
            INNER JOIN ALLGROUPS 
            ON TBL_GROUPS.GROUPFATHER = ALLGROUPS.GROUPID
    )
SELECT * FROM ALLGROUPS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE, for your function you can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @tbl_access TABLE (userid INT, groupid INT)
DECLARE @tbl_groups TABLE (groupid INT, groupfather INT)

INSERT  @tbl_access 
VALUES 
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(2, 4)

INSERT  @tbl_groups
VALUES  
(1, -1),
(2, 1),
(3, -1),
(4, 2),
(5, 4)

DECLARE @UserID INT = 1

;WITH cte AS (

    SELECT  a.*
    FROM    @tbl_groups a
    JOIN    @tbl_access c ON
            c.userid = @UserID
    AND     c.groupid = a.groupid

    UNION   ALL

    SELECT  b.*
    FROM    @tbl_groups b
    JOIN    cte d ON
            d.groupid = b.groupfather
)

SELECT  DISTINCT groupid
FROM    cte
```